# Update webBrowser html after ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, browser

I need to get the updated html of webBrowser after it gets updated by an AJAX function

For example, I navigate to "page1.asp", but "page1.asp" includes an iframe that loads content from another page. It also has an jQoery function that display a Submit button after xx seconds.

My question is how can I get the most recent html from webBrowser?

I tried update but no luck,

```
webBrowser.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well its a bit tricky question you need to follow the following guidelines correctly in order to achieve your goals.

1. you need to create a timer on the form. bind it with tick and give an interval about 500 ms.
2. write this code in the timer_tick event:

   if (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
3. Once you find the ready state completed then you look for the html element that you think will be updated after completion of ajax request.

You could do this way to check any element:

```
        HtmlElementCollection forms = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form");
        HtmlElement form = null;
        foreach (HtmlElement el in forms)
        {
            string name = el.GetAttribute("name");
            if (name == "DATA")
            {
                form = el;
                break;
            }
        }
```

4) Once you have got your element you may carry on your work.

Update: Here is the timer tick coding that you can extend as per your needs 
Make sure you have set your `Timer1.Inverval = 100` (100 milli seconds)

```
    private void Timer1_Tick(sender, args) 
    {
        Application.DoEvents();

// make sure your are pulling right element id
        HtmlElement cTag = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("myelement");         

        if(cTag != null) // if elemnt is found than its fine. 
        { 
            cTag.SetAttribute("value", "Eugene");
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
// dont worry, the ajax request is still in progress... just wait on it and move on for the next tick. 
        }
        Application.DoEvents(); // you can call it at the end too.
    }
```

Comment: but this didn't fix the problem of frames? the documentText is still not populated?

Comment: impossible! You must enable a timer, and look for the browser state to  become "complete", when ajax is being executed the browser is still busy. You need to call App.DoEvents() function inside the timer tick so you get the most updated stated of the webbrowser. Dude. I have written many many scrapers and I know how exactly it works.

Comment: Let me tell you one more thing, the documentText will never written you the recent content. You must have to find the element manually and then pick its html and get your work done around it.

Comment: I'm doing Application.DoEvents() in the timer and I'm waiting enough time, but when I try to set the element, I'm getting null reference error. See what I'm doing


HtmlElement cTag = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("myelement");

cTag.SetAttribute("value", "Eugene");

Comment: @EugeneYousif what is the interval of Timer_Tick? You should wait for few seconds and keep checking the element until its null or you have reached your wait time to abandon it. I am updating my answer for the timer tick function.

Comment: @EugeneYousif Can you share the source website so I can look into it and find you something? I mean, I really want to solve this problem. I recently have done some more complex data extraction from a very intelligent anti-scraping website.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebBrowser.DocumentText()`.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx)

> This property contains the text of the current document, even if another document has been requested. If you set the value of this property and then immediately retrieve it again, the value retrieved may be different than the value set if the WebBrowser control has not had time to load the new content. You can retrieve the new value in a DocumentCompleted event handler. Alternatively, you can block the thread until the document is loaded by calling the Thread.Sleep method in a loop until the DocumentText property returns the value that you originally set it to.

Try running calling DocumentText() inside a DocumentCompleted() event handler. If you can't do that because the iFrame doesn't throw this event, just set a timer and retrieve the text every few seconds.