# vb.net webbrowser doesnt receive streamed data anymore

Tags: vb.net

Here is a website which gives streamed data about currencies
 http://fr.investing.com/currencies/streaming-forex-rates-majors

Few days ago, my webbrowser had no difficulty to receive the streamed data, so without refreshing, i always had prices up to date...
But now, all price don't move anymore , price are not streamed anymore...

***Can someone make a form with a webbrowser inside and in url properties paste 
http://fr.investing.com/currencies/streaming-forex-rates-majors
and tell me if he receives streamed prices or not...***
It will tell me if the problem comes from me or from the website.

Best regards

Comment: Of course, hi everyone :)

Comment: Why is that site not secure ?

Comment: Do you mean there is no s behind http? I really don't know but trust me this site is well known and has many many visitors by day.

Comment: https://fr.investing.com/currencies/streaming-forex-rates-majors I just added a s, I don t know if it helps

Comment: It's no change, just figured something of importance in the financial industry, especially with a high valued domain like "invest.com", they could spend the near nothing expense of adding a common layer of security.   In any case, you can try this [webbrowser ajax problem solved](http://blog.search-visible.com/c-webbrowser-innerhtml-ajax-problem-solved/)  horribly formatted document, but I believe relevant to receiving update notifications when content has changed.  In your case, probably the `cr1` for `GetElementById`  (c#, but vb.net is pretty much the same)

Comment: Also, this might be of some assistance :  [Update webBrowser html after ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302754/update-webbrowser-html-after-ajax)

Comment: @Kraang Prime Thanks a lot for your answers, your links are very interessant, but I reallly need to get streamed data... I need to know where the problem comes from ... can you please make a simple form with a webrowser and navigate to the link and tell me if data change ? It would help me a lot

Comment: I need to add that I have streamed data with firefox and internet explorer 11 , but not with vb.net webbrowser :S

Comment: The information I have given is essentially the nuts and bolts how to write an event to trigger when data inside a target element changes after the page has completed rendering.

Comment: Yes I saw, but the problem is that I have to be the fastest I can to treat the data, and in my case, in my webbrowser no element are even changed....